# jQuery validate custom messages not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am unable to get custom error messages working for the jQuery validation plugin.  I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 and jquery validation plugin 1.9.0.

My form is simple:

```
<form id="registrationform">
  <label for="rid">User Id</label><br/>
  <input id="rid" type="text" class="required"/><br/>
  <label for="remail">Email</label><br/>
  <input id="remail" type="text" class="required email"/>
</form>
```

My javascript is simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#registrationform").validate({
        rules: {
            rid : {
                required : true
            },
            remail: {
                required : true,
                email : true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            rid : {
                required : "id can not be empty"
            },
            remail: {
                required: "email can not be empty",
                email : "enter a valid email"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure the rules: {} are specified correctly.  In reality, since you already have the class='required email', entries in your HTML, you shouldn't need any special rules.   I'd try removing the rules section, clearing your browser cache, and trying again.

Comment: JMC, I tried it without the rules first.  That didn't solve it.  Sam Tyson's solution, adding name attributes, solved the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As crazy as it sounds, this is resolved by adding the name attribute to each of the input controls.

```
<form id="registrationform">
  <label for="rid">User Id</label><br/>
  <input id="rid" name="rid" type="text" class="required"/><br/>
  <label for="remail">Email</label><br/>
  <input id="remail" name="remail" type="text" class="required email"/>
</form>
```

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9um6X/3/) to prove it out.

Comment: It looks like the idOrName() function in validate() is stumbling over the lack of the name attribute or confusing the checkable() result.

Comment: Sam, thanks so much.  I've confirmed your solution in both my isolated test case and in my app.

Comment: What's so crazy about that?  [The plugin requires that the markup for each input contains a `name` attribute](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#markup-recommendations).